# WebSphere error 404 SRVE0295E

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-7

I've got a strange problem where an application I'm deploying to WebSphere can't seem to access its resources. I can access the main page just fine, but when index.jsp tries to reference the Javascript file it relies on, it gets a 404. Specifically, "Error 404: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 404".

The Javascript is referenced as `<script type="text/javascript" src="/contextRoot/someDir/scripts/myJavascript.js"></script>`

The main entry page for the site is located at `http://localhost:9080/contextRoot/index.jsp` and it loads fine.

If I try to navigate my browser to `http://localhost:9080/contextRoot/someDir/scripts/myJavascript.js` I get `Error 404: SRVE0295E`, even though the path to the file in my WebSphere installed application `$myCell/myApp.ear/myWARModule.war/index.jsp` and `$myCell/myApp.ear/myWARModule.war/someDir/scripts/myJavascript.js` are both valid, the only resource I can access from a browser is `index.jsp`.

Does anyone know what could cause this error?

(Running on WebSphere 7.0.0.29)

Comment: Probably it is not that, but check if you have `ibm-web-ext.xml` file in the `WEB-INF` folder and if it has `enable-file-serving` set to true.

Comment: @Gas: Actually, that *was* it. You should post that as an answer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serve static files like images, html, or javascript application needs to have file serving enabled. You can do it by editing `ibm-web-ext.xml` file in the `WEB-INF` folder, and ensuring that `enable-file-serving` is set to `true`.

Comment: Hi  I have the same issue , but the error i get while redirecting to a page is "Error 400: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 400" . enable-file-serving is already set to true. any help would be appreciated , thanks

Comment: @yash If it would be the same issue, same solution would work ;). Create new question and describe your problem in more details.