# How to access an specific resource path though the IBM Websphere Application server port 9080?

Tags: websphere

I want to access specific images of the application server image directory through the IBM Websphere application server port **9080**.

Ex: Let's assume my base image directory is "C:/myApplication/images" and it contains an image called "abc.png". So, I want to access that image from the below URL.

> http://localhost:9080/my-images/abc.png

In the Apache Tomcat we can configure it in /conf/server.xml file as below.

> < Context  docBase="/C:/myApplication/images" path="my-images" />

But I want to know how to configure that base resource path in the Websphere Admin Console to access images through the Websphere application server port 9080 ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to just serve directory from WAS, this is typically done via Http Server (e.g. IHS, Apache).

To do it from WAS you need to deploy "empty" web application (descriptors are needed), and configure it correctly, e.g. with "context-root" set to "/" or whatever base path you need.
You will also need to enable file serving and set extended context root.

Check these posts for hints:

- [Add a new webapp context to the Websphere server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225704/add-a-new-webapp-context-to-the-websphere-server/43228915#43228915)
- [Create ibm-web.ext.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29497188/3701228)
- [Enable file serving](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26935858/3701228)